# using nested field values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

in mongo:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("519733333fb6664b5d000000"),
   "email": "email@email.com",
   "dates": {
       "pre_register": "2013-05-18 04:53:38" 
   } 
}
```

my model:

```
class Member
      include Mongoid::Document
      store_in collection:'member'

      field :email
      field :dates
end
```

how to use the field **dates.pre_register**? I tried this:

```
field :dates.pre_register
```

but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `field` [actually defines string types by default](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields).

I think you should think the other way around. Let mongoid generate the mongodb document for you. One way to achieve what you are looking for is to define another `Mongoid::Document` "Date" and have your class 
`Member` embed id as:

```
embedds_many :dates
```

This would work. If you don't want to define a custom `Mongoid::Document` for that, just use a  hash field like:

```
field :dates, :type => Hash
```

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to use this with rails_admin but seems this gem has no support for editing hash/array field